# Continuous Deployment Activity +svn

Tags: svn, deployment, version-control

Suppose I have a file called a.txt and person X works on it and check-in his code into SVN. Testing team has verified the code and promoted it to UAT. Now I get a production issue and person Y checks out the same code and fixes the issue and pushes it to Production environment after certification from the testing team. Now the code the person X checked-in also goes to PROD, which is not correct.This is a continuous activity (daily activity), so creating branches everyday will not solve the issue. Awaiting your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. There **are not** such "commonly accepted" term is Subversion as "Environment" - and understanding of it for different people *may differ*
2. "Environment" in any case isn't strictly related to real SVN-objects (branches, repositories, revisions) and can be implemented by different ways
3. In your use-case code at last step **will differ** in different environments. Let's name initial state `STABLE`, X-user changes `FEATURE` and Y-user change `BUGFIX`. In this scenario and three-layers environments (DEV-UAT-PROD) you'll get:

before

```
DEV  -> STABLE
UAT  -> STABLE
PROD -> STABLE
```

after

```
DEV  -> STABLE+FEATURE
UAT  -> STABLE+FEATURE
PROD -> STABLE+BUGFIX
```

and **PROD != UAT**

Somebody must backport `BUGFIX` into `DEV` and state `STABLE+FEATURE+BUGFIX` must be tested|promoted in usual way

How backporting will be implemented depends on the *only yours* principles of separation of liability and code (separate repositories or just branches in common repo will use different techniques for transferring data)

Anyway, I consider hotfixing on PROD as bad practice: short-term branch on DEV (from `STABLE`) with casual promoting cycle (and merging later in DEV `FEATURE+BUGFIX` into common revision) will give less headache (no unsupported by workflow backports) and use standard well-tested patterns